# Enable AWS Management Console in AWS Directory Service SimpleAD Programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-directory-services, amazon-directory-services

I am trying to automate the deployment of an AWS Directory Service SimpleAD using CloudFormation. I would like to enable access to the AWS Management Console programmatically via CloudFormation or API calls.

I've spent quite some time going through the [relative AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/aws_console_access.html), but all I could find is how to do this using the [web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80O3S.png). I would like to enable this without clicking around the AWS console.

Does AWS provide an API for this at all?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to enable AWS Console with AD you first needs to create your AD in AWS (from the options: *AWS Managed Microsoft AD, Simple AD, AD Connector or Amazon Cognito User Pools*) and, once your AD is enabled, you can click on your AD and access the page **web interface**.

Check this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_create_access_url.html

To do this programmatically, you can [create an alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/devguide/API_CreateAlias.html), with the pattern **https://alias.awsapps.com**, where alias is the name prefix of the service you want to enable for your AD. But AWS doesn't recommend you do this because you cannot exclude or reuse the alias in your AD.